# OnDraw not getting called

Tags: c++, scroll, mfc

I'm trying to display an image in `CScrollView`-derived class:

[C++ CScrollView, how to scroll an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957200/c-cscrollview-how-to-scroll-an-image)

So I want to override `OnDraw`, to move the code from `OnPaint` to `OnDraw`. But I can't. Every time I call `Invalidate()` only `OnPaint` is getting called.

```
void CCardioAppView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{

}

void CCardioAppView::OnPaint()
{
    if (theApp.ImageFolderPath == _T("")) return;
//---------------------метод № 2 с CPictureHolder-------------------------------
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    CBitmap bmp;
    BITMAP b;
    HBITMAP hbitmap;
    CRect rect;
    auto bmp_iter = theApp.FullBmpMap.find(m_iCurrentImage);

    if (bmp_iter == theApp.FullBmpMap.end()) return;

    hbitmap = bmp_iter->second; 
    bmp.Attach((*bmp_iter).second);
    bmp.GetObject(sizeof(BITMAP), &b);

    GetClientRect(&rect);
    scaleRect = rect;
    OriginalWidth = b.bmWidth;
    OriginalHeight = b.bmHeight;
    if (rect.Height() <= b.bmHeight)
        scaleRect.right = rect.left + ((b.bmWidth*rect.Height()) / b.bmHeight);
    else if (rect.Height() > b.bmHeight)
    {
        scaleRect.right = b.bmWidth;
        scaleRect.bottom = b.bmHeight;
    }
    scaleRect.right = scaleRect.right + scale_koef_g;
    scaleRect.bottom = scaleRect.bottom + scale_koef_v;

    pic.CreateFromBitmap(hbitmap);
    pic.Render(&dc, scaleRect, rect);

    (*bmp_iter).second.Detach();
    (*bmp_iter).second.Attach(bmp);
    bmp.Detach();

    int isclWidth = scaleRect.Width();
    int isclHeight = scaleRect.Height();
    int irHeight = rect.Height();
    int irWidth = rect.Width();

    if ((isclWidth> irWidth)||(isclHeight > irHeight))
    {
        SetScrollSizes(MM_TEXT, CSize(isclWidth, isclHeight));
    }
    else SetScrollSizes(MM_TEXT, CSize(irWidth, irHeight));
}
```

Comment: Don't be afraid to read the documentation ([Drawing in a View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssdhfz2t.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

Of course it doesn't call `OnDraw()`.  When you call `Invalidate()` it ends up with a `WM_PAINT` message for the `CView` derived class.  The default implementation of `CView::OnPaint()` gets a paint DC and then it later calls `CView::OnDraw()`.  You are overriding `OnPaint()` and you never call `OnDraw()` in your `OnPaint()` handler.

You can move some of your `OnPaint()` code into `OnDraw()` except for obvious stuff like `CPaintDC dc(this);`

After that you can delete your `OnPaint()` declaration and implementation.  Then, delete your `ON_WM_PAINT()` message map entry.  I can't vouch either way for your drawing code.